# linking Visualforce pages to display in mobile

Tags: visualforce

I’ve created several visualforce pages that are Available for Salesforce mobile apps. The home page contains buttons which link to the other visualforce pages I created. When I log into Salesforce1 the home page displays as mobile; however, whenever I click on the buttons the next visualforce page displays desktop. I would like for the pages to display in mobile if I am logged into Salesforce1. I've tried different ways as you can see in the code below, please help. Thanks!

```
<apex:page >
<FORM>
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Search Patient/Guest" onClick="self.location.href=  ('https://na17.salesforce.com/_ui/search/ui/UnifiedSearchResults')" 
 style=" background-color:#af0400; width: 330px; font-size: 22px; font-weight: bold; color: #ffffff;" /><br />
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="New Patient" onClick="parent.location='https://na17.salesforce.com/apex/Naperville_New_Pt_Page'"
style=" background-color:#af0400; width: 330px; font-size: 22px; font-weight: bold; color: #ffffff;" /><br />
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="New Guest" onClick="self.location.href=('Naperville_New_Gt_Page')" 
 style=" background-color:#af0400; width: 330px; font-size: 22px; font-weight: bold; color: #ffffff;" /><br />
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="New Relationship" onClick="self.location.href=('Naperville_Relationship')" 
 style=" background-color:#af0400; width: 330px; font-size: 22px; font-weight: bold; color: #ffffff;" /><br />
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="New Visit" onClick="self.location.href=('Naperville_Visit_Page')" 
 style=" background-color:#af0400; width: 330px; font-size: 22px; font-weight: bold; color: #ffffff;" />
</FORM><!--to allow code formatting-->
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Welcome to SF.SE Jessica. Are the pages you're referencing e.g. `Naperville_New_Pt_Page` either enabled for SF1 or created as Flex Pages? You may want to take a look at the [Salesforce1 Mobile App Admin Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1appadmin.meta/salesforce1appadmin/) and the
[Salesforce1 Mobile App Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/) for more.

Answer (score 0):

Does this still happen if you use the $Page action to build the link to the VisualForce page?

**Example**

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!$Page.Naperville_New_Pt_Page}">Link Text</apex:outputLink>
```